# MySQL query for merging two tables to get a single result

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables with a single common field.
Here is how these two table structures are

Table 1

```
+--ID--+--Title----+----others---+
| 123  | Title 1   | other values|
| 124  | Title 2   | other values|
| 125  | Title 3   | other values|
| 126  | Title 4   | other values|
+------+-----------+-------------+
```

Table 2

```
+--ID--+--Tag ID--+----others---+
| 123  |   11     | other values|
| 123  |   12     | other values|
| 123  |   13     | other values|
| 123  |   14     | other values|
| 124  |   15     | other values|
| 124  |   16     | other values|
| 125  |   17     | other values|
| 126  |   18     | other values|
+------+----------+-------------+
```

I want to show that Article `ID 123` have `4 tags` i.e 11,12,13 & 14 like the table below

```
+--Article ID--+--Article Title--+--Tags--+--Tag IDs------+
|     123      |    Title 1      |    4   | 11, 12, 13, 14|
|     124      |    Title 2      |    2   |     15, 16    |
|     125      |    Title 3      |    1   |        17     |
|     126      |    Title 4      |    1   |        18     |
+--------------+-----------------+--------+---------------+
```

I'm very new to PHP and MySQL and trying to learn it.

Someone please help me to know how I can get the desired result.

Comment: please show us your code and tell us where you are getting error.

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT will be your friend here

Comment: Hint : Use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

Comment: You need to clarify if you have 2 or 3 common fields (1 for between each table) or just one for all 3. Table names would also be nice, they hint at what relations you need (which btw you didn't enumerate). Please edit your question to make everything clearer.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies, I'm checking all of these responses and will surely mark the answer as soon as I get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.id AS 'Article ID',
t1.title AS 'Article Title', 
count( t2.tag_id ) AS 'Tags', 
GROUP_CONCAT( t2.Tag_Id order by t2.Tag_id ASC) AS `Tag IDs`
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON ( t1.id = t2.id )
GROUP BY t1.id;
```

Hope this works!

Comment: This would order the Tag IDs in ascending order!

Comment: Your answer is really great and it is working very well, I just have a little more request, i.e I have some more columns on Table 2 and also want to fetch the data of those fields. Can you please help me a bit more on this? The array I'm getting now is like this `object(stdClass)#418 (4) {
  ["Article ID"]=>
  string(4) "6510"
  ["Article Title"]=>
  string(10) "My Article Title"
  ["Tags"]=>
  string(1) "5"
  ["Tag IDs"]=>
  string(26) "139,140,141,142,143"`

Comment: I think I just got it.. but it is not complete though. I have added lines like this `t2.active AS 'active'` just after `line 2` on the above code. The problem is when I'm `var_dump()`ing the array all datas in those fields are getting merged and only the values of the first row is showing up.

Comment: Finally I got it right. I used more `GROUP_CONCAT( t2.url) AS 'url',` parameters to get the result. Thanks everyone for your kind help.

Answer (score 2):

This query should work (with some tweaking).

```
SELECT `ID` AS `t1`.`Article ID`, `t2`.`Title` AS `Article Title`, COUNT(`t2`.`ID`) AS `Tags`,
GROUP_CONCAT(`t2`.`ID`) AS `Tag IDs` FROM `Articles` AS `t1`
LEFT JOIN `Tags` AS `t2` ON `t1`.`ID` = `t2`.`ID`
GROUP BY `t1`.`ID`
```

There's a couple of other options to the `GROUP_CONCAT` function, but the defaults should work fine for what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Merging tables is done by using `JOIN` (LEFT, RIGHT INNER) keyword. For example:

```
SELECT T1.*, T2.*, COUNT(T2.ID) AS TAG_COUNT, GROUP_CONCAT(T2.ID) AS TAG_IDS
FROM TABLE1 T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 T2 
ON T1.TAG_ID = T2.ID
```

This type of joining structure suggest, that you have a common filed, by which the join itself is made. 
In your table structure I assume, that first table T1 is Article's table, second one is Tags table. In this case you need to have a field in your T1 table, which corresponds to the field in T2, this is most probably ID.

Edit: As final step you need to concatenate the results in order to achieve the desired structure, as many of the answers said - use `GROUP_CONCAT()` function.

Answer (score 0):

As somebody already mentioned in the comments, you should use GROUP_CONCAT(). Here are some examples and options - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table1.*, 
       table2.tagidgroup 
FROM   table1 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT id, 
                          Group_concat(tagid SEPARATOR ','  ) AS tagidgroup 
                   FROM   table2 
                   GROUP  BY id) Table2 
               ON table1.id = Table2.id
```